# Poetry install hash for package.whl not found in known hashes

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

When running `poetry install` I get the following error

`Hash for some-package (a.b.c) from archive some-package-a.b.c....whl not found in known hashes`

poetry version `^1.3`

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

`rm -r ~/.cache/pypoetry/cache` and failing that maybe try `rm -r ~/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts`

Then ruunning `poetry install` again.

Comment: While this did not resolve my issue, note that on windows the cache dir, as stated in the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#cache-directory), is at `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\pypoetry\Cache` (PS)

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Patterson's answer is correct, but the cache location of poetry depends on your OS.

In MacOS, it's located by default in `~/Library/Caches/pypoetry`.
[Reference](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#:%7E:text=The%20path%20to%20the%20cache,AppData%5CLocal%5Cpypoetry%5CCache)